# Vertical Alignment In a List Box

Tags: visual-c++, listbox, vertical-alignment

I use a listbox in (visualC++ 2008) as a log window, and I use SetItemHeight() to obtain some space between entries. How can I align my entries vertically so that they are vertically centered?

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to do an owner-draw list box to get vertical centering.